# visual basic 2010, Importing excel files to my SQL using bulkcopy

Tags: vb.net

hello guys I'm having a problem with a project that I build
I'm trying to import excel files to sql server 2016 using bulkcopy and I got this error

"'DAFTAR1$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long"

I think there is a problem with this code 
Dim query_excel As String = "SELECT * from [" & file & "$]"

i tried all of this code on another pc and it works perfectly but on my pc it's getting that error, I don't know what did I wrong, I'm using visual basic 2010 professional edition, sql management server 2016 and microsoft office 2016

can anyone help me to figure what is wrong with the code ?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TextBox1.Text)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim koneksi_excel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & TextBox1.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""")
    koneksi_excel.Open()

    Dim query_excel As String = "SELECT * from [" & file & "$]"
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query_excel, koneksi_excel)
    Dim rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim koneksi As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()
    Dim koneksidatabase As String = "server=DESKTOP-KJQ8PNO\SQLEXPRESS;database=otto;Integrated Security=True"
    koneksi.ConnectionString = koneksidatabase


    koneksi.Open()
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query_excel, koneksi_excel)
    da.Fill(dt)


    Using bulkcopy As SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(koneksi)
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = file
        bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(rd)
        rd.Close()


        MsgBox("Data uploaded to database", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Uploaded")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the name of the Worksheet you're trying to import. My guess is that it's just called "Daftar1", rather than "Daftar1$"

Comment: hey david thank you for your suggest, I tried not to put $ but it still giving me the same error, I wonder that there is something wrong in this code     " Select * From ["& File & "$]" 
I tried all of the code that I wrote on another pc and it worked perfectly, so I don't know how to do

Comment: Is there always only one worksheet in the Excel file? Or maybe 2, but one blank one named "Sheet1$"?

Comment: there's only one sheet in each excel file, so what I mean is, I have several excel files that I need to upload to sql server database, I also created those tables in database and I named them the same as the excel files

Comment: Are you using a `DataGridView` or anything to view the file you're importing?

Answer (score 0):

***If*** you're using a `DataGridView` or some other grid to view the data, this is one way that you can view the data and load it into the grid.

```
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
      ofd.InitialDirectory = dir
      ofd.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx| XLS Files (*.xls)|*.xls"
      ofd.FilterIndex = 1

    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
       txtFile.Text = ofd.FileName

       fi = New FileInfo(ofd.FileName)
       fileName = ofd.FileName

       excel = fi.FullName

       eCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                                   excel & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;';")
       eCon.Open()

      Dim dtSheets As DataTable = eCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
      Dim listSheet As New List(Of String)
      Dim drSheet As DataRow

      For Each drSheet In dtSheets.Rows
           If drSheet.Item("TABLE_NAME").ToString() <> "Sheet1$" Then
              listSheet.Add(drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
          Else
          End If
      Next

     Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

     Dim myTable = ""
     myTable = listSheet.Item(0)

     da = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTable), eCon)
     ds = New DataSet
     da.Fill(ds, myTable)
     Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).Copy()
```

From here, set the `dt` as the grid `DataSource`. This way you know you're always getting the first worksheet, and don't have to worry about what the name is as such, the program is getting it for you.

Have a play around a let me know. Alternatively, you can just use this code to get the Excel sheet and use what you have already for the import.

Comment: no I don't use datagridview, I will give it shot david
thank you so much man I really appreciate what you did 
I'll let you know if it works or not

Comment: hey david, I tried your code and it works fine just to show the file in datagrid, but I still get this error when I try to upload it.
"The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'C:\Users\WilliamNick\Desktop\DAFTAR1.xlsx'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."
it's so weird, the code just work perfectly but still getting the same error

Comment: I think the problem is around this code 

Dim koneksi_excel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & TextBox1.Text & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1""")
        koneksi_excel.Open()

        Dim query_excel As String = "SELECT * from [file]"
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query_excel, koneksi_excel)
        Dim rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: So use an `OpenFileDialog`. That way you're selecting the file to use. As long as the connection string is correct, it won't have any issues.

Comment: hey david I figured out the problem, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it, thank you buddy